# What are XForm In and XFormOut Pins in directshow?

Tags: c++, directshow

What are XForms pins? How are they different than normal Input/output pins? Do they behave different than normal pins when connecting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How are they different than normal Input/output pins?

Different just by naming, suggesting that "X" stands for "Trans-". The naming actually comes from underlying base class `CTransformFilter`.

> Do they behave different than normal pins when connecting them?

No.